# kitchen aid 30" cooktop amperage requirements

Tags: electrical-panel

Have 50A 3 prong BOX. Need another 50A 3 prong for second 240A appliance Can I go from 50A to 100A breaker and "bridge second 3 prong line? OR do I need to wire a second romex from additional 50A breaker to install additional 3 prong wall receptacle?

Comment: Quite sure by code each needs it's own breaker and cable.  Going to 100 amp breaker you would also need to have much larger gauge wires(replace the cable there anyway) and need new stoves to handle 100 amps.  Think a new 50 amp breaker and cable is looking like a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Lots going on here. The cable going to the existing box is most likely 6 ga copper or 4 ga aluminum.   Both are most likely rated for 50 amps. If individual wires in conduit, depending upon the exact wires, you might be able to push it to 60.  We just can't give you a good answer bc you haven't supplied enough info.

Next: no way can you safely or legally "double up" and double the breaker size and not change the wiring.   You'll need a new run to your panel.

2nd Next:  3 prong (2 hots and a ground) are no longer allowed.  You'll need to install a 4 prong outlet (2 hots, neutral and a ground) and run 4 conductor cable, copper or AL ( I prefer copper even though it's more expensive) If AL, don't forget the "goop" (Noalox) when making your connections.

So the short answer is NO you can't just double up with another high power outlet and double the breaker size, that's how fires get started.

Code may even require dedicated circuits.  Others here with  better knowledge of the code will probably chime in soon.   At any rate, dedicated circuits for high power appliances is a very good idea.

Comment: Generally speaking good and answer. Two minor points: 1 - Unlikely, but there can be 3-wire 240V legal connections - NEMA 6-50. No neutral. Unlikely because the vast majority of US electric ranges/ovens/etc. need neutral = NEMA 10 (3-wire obsolete) or NEMA 14 (4-wire). 2 - I believe there are some limited circumstances allowing cooktop and oven as separate receptacles on one 50A circuit. Can't remember the specifics, and separate circuits are much better for a number of reasons. Not enough detail from OP to even know if that would be an option.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact      Thanks for the input / comment.   I learn stuff here every day.   Still, I think it's best practice to run  /3 plus ground on a new run, "just in case" even if the OP installs a 3 prong outlet.   If he doubles up on the outlets (and I sure hope he doesn't upgrade the breaker), if he fires up too much stuff at once, he'll be tripping breakers.   Again, thanks for the input.